# Block based Image Caching Library for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, caching, static-libraries, block

What is currently fastest block based image caching library available for iOS which talks & return only UIImage instead of NSData.

Apart from MKNetworkKit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if its the fastest, but a very good lib is [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). You can use block syntax and it loads images from web or cache with minimum required code.